# PyQt4: extract values from rawHeaderList

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

I want to read headers from the `rawHeaderList` using `QNetworkReply` how to perform this action? I try to iterate but it says `QNetworkRaply` object is not iterable, simple printing says `<PyQt4.QtNetwork.QNetworkReply object at 0x1837958>`.

Here is my code

```
...
request = QNetworkRequest(QUrl('http://www.kg'))
manager = QNetworkAccessManager()

reply = manager.get(request)

'''
How to get the list of headers?
'''
```

Sultan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many ways. You can use `reply.rawHeaderPairs()`, for example:

```
import pprint, sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtNetwork

app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(sys.argv)
request = QtNetwork.QNetworkRequest(QtCore.QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"))
manager = QtNetwork.QNetworkAccessManager()
reply = manager.get(request)
while not reply.isFinished():
    app.processEvents()

try:
    # for Qt 4.7 and higher:
    pprint.pprint(reply.rawHeaderPairs())
except AttributeError:
    # for Qt < 4.7:
    for header in reply.rawHeaderList():
        pprint.pprint((header, reply.rawHeader(header)))
```

See also `QNetworkReply` documentation, especially `rawHeader`, `rawHeaderList`, `header` and other methods.

Edit note: I have updated the example to make it compatible with older Qt/PyQt versions (before 4.7).

Comment: This code gives an error: `AttributeError: 'QNetworkReply' object has no attribute 'rawHeaderPairs'`

Comment: Which version of PyQt4 are you using? This code works fine on my machine with PyQt4 4.8.3. Docs suggest that rawHeaderPairs exists in Qt versions 4.7 and above.

Comment: Anyway, update example, should now work also with earlier Qt versions.